# spawning a simple_box in gazebo, box oscillates

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With electric running on Ubuntu 11.10, if I run the following two commands

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
roslaunch gazebo_worlds simple_box.launch
```

I would expect to get a 5cm by 5m by 10cm box spawned at position (1,0,2). Effectively, that is what happens. But then the box starts oscillating around (0,0,2), moving from (1,0,2) to (-1,0,2). I don't understand why this is happening. Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks,

-J

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32531/spawning-a-simple_box-in-gazebo,-box-oscillates/) by [juancamilog](https://answers.ros.org/users/2242/juancamilog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-04-25**:
Yes ! it oscillates as a pendulum !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

looking my simple_box.urdf I've got:

```
  <joint name="my_box_joint" type="continuous" >
    <!-- axis is in the parent link frame coordintates -->
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <parent link="world" />
    <child link="my_box" />
    <!-- initial pose of my_box joint/link in the parent frame coordiantes -->
    <origin xyz="0 0 2" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </joint>
```

So looking at the rest of the urdf: the joint is at (0 0 2) and the mass is centered at (1 0 2).   So the mass should pivot around (0 0 2) since gravity is acting on the box.

---

Originally posted by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) with karma: 235 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2